# Tango raw depth data - update?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-project-tango, depth

I bought the lenovo phab 2 pro supporting the tango project from google. Using this setup, it it possible to obtain depth data in form of a pointcloud. But this is not what I need. I would prefer to obtain data in a more raw format like possible to be obtained by the Kinect, where each pixel of the imageplane is assigned a depth value. 
My question therefore: **Is the depth data of the phab2 (or any tango device) possible to be obtained in such a raw format where each pixel is assigned a depth value?**

My research lead me to countless unsolved cases (typing tango raw data or similar in google, stackoverflow etc.). That is why I am looking for any updates on this issue or if anybody has already found an idea on how to solve this problem or has a lead? Also I would be greatful if somebody could tell me how, or if, it is possible to access the depth cameras "raw data" without using tango?! Currently I use the android sdk with tango's C-API.

Comment: I restructured the text and hope my question is clear now. Please remove the hold status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no depth image directly available through Tango API. In fact, the raw data in Tango's consideration is point clouds. In order to get a depth image, you would have to project those points onto camera's image plane, and perform certain amount of upsampling to get a good result.

[Tango Support Library](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/) does have serveral [upsample methods](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/group/depth-interpolation-support#group___depth_interpolation_support_1ga03a4e39d813814d837c24216f3ee105d). There's also a [rgb-depth-sync example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_rgb_depth_sync_example) code from Tango shows how to perform the depth points projection.

Comment: Since I am newbie to android and especially to tango another approach would be to not use the tango project and access the depth data "directly" from the camera. Is this a possibility or do I miss something?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of bypassing TangoAPI to access the depth camera on Tango device. In fact, I think* the raw data from the depth camera driver is point cloud too.