# Accessing depth camera via android sdk

Tags: android, camera, google-project-tango

I am kind of new to android developement and would like to use the data captured by the depth sensor of my phab 2 pro. (IR sensor) I know, that accessing the standard camera is possible via the Camera API using the camera2 class. But I do not know how to do so, or is it even possible, by using the phab 2's depth camera!?
I already got familiar with the Tango C API but it does not provide the raw depth data, where depth is represented according to the image plane pixels.

Long story short question:
**Can I work with the depth camera of my smarthphone similar to the standard one?**

Comment: Unclear why you need to access the depth camera via camera api when you can get access to the data in a Tango Point Cloud https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/struct/tango-point-cloud

Comment: I do not need the point cloud representation of the depth data. Rather I need the depth information as "raw" pixel data. Where each pixel of the image plane is assigned with a depth value (equal e.g. using the kinect)

Comment: There's no raw depth image from Tango's stand of point. All data comes from HAL is as points. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572682/tango-raw-depth-data-update

Comment: That tango url no longer works.

Comment: You can find the SDK docs on archive.org.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to capture a point cloud and use `TangoSupport_upsampleImageBilateral()` to interpolate the depth, for each pixel.

See:

- https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/depth
- https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/group/depth-interpolation-support#group___depth_interpolation_support_1ga03a4e39d813814d837c24216f3ee105d

Note that if you're trying to pair a depth image with an image from the color camera, they will possibly (always, in the case of the Yellowstone tablet) be captured at different times.

Comment: Tango has shut down. How to access this data without tango?

Comment: If you're using a Tango device, you can find the SDK documentation via archive.org and the runtime libraries in https://github.com/6DoFF/tango-examples-c , however I'm not aware of any other API for accessing the depth sensor on these devices.

Comment: There are some Tango developers still hanging around arcore.slack.com.  You could try asking there.