# Can I obtain raw depth data/map from PHAB2 Pro?

Tags: google-project-tango, depth

I want to buy a Lenovo PHAB2 Pro mobile phone to learn Tango's depth perception.  So can I obtain raw depth maps or data from PHAB2 Pro? And if possible could you tell me how to do it? Is Tango C API useful? Or does PHAB2 Pro have other open-source package or Development kit that I can use?

Thanks！:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 & 2 - Raw Depth Maps are not available natively, but for an idea of how to get them see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572682/tango-raw-depth-data-update).  I've not done it.
However you do have the [Point Cloud](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango-point-cloud) representation of the data to work with.

3 & 4 - It seems the majority of developers do not directly use the C API, but instead work with the UNITY SDK. There is a very good reference on which APIs to choose [here](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/overview).  The PHAB2 does not have any different Development kit from the Dev Kit tablet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason that I want to obtain raw depth data is that I want to see if Tango's depth maps have depth hole. Depth maps upsampling from Point Cloud won't have depth hole, is it right?